# File System problem in dual boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows-10

I have a peculiar problem, for which I am not able to find a solution even after much searching on the web.
I have a dual boot with windows10 and ubuntu 16.04. Till  this morning my system was working fine, but when I opened my laptop  this morning I found the following peculiar behavior :

In windows :

1)All the files and folders have been made read-only. Clicking on any file(or folder) moves it to the Recycle bin(deletes it) giving the error dialog box "The specified file or folder couldn't be found".

In Ubuntu:

1)While booting, sometimes the ubuntu purple-white dots appear with the screen flickering, and it takes a long amount of time to boot. Or, a purple screen appears(no ubuntu symbol or dots) and the os boots up relatively faster.

2)After providing the password, everything works fine(as in I am able to open different file formats, unlike windows) but a rather peculiar thing happens. When I open a terminal, or open a text file or open a browser(any where a text input can be provided), random dots(...) keeps on appearing(for example when typing the command "htop", due to the random dots "..h.t.o...p" is put in terminal).

I would appreciate if anyone can point me to the possible cause of this behavior(possibly hardware or malware) and how to solve this.
P.S : I tried executing sfc /scannow in windows but it didn't help.

Comment: Have you been mounting and accessing your Windows system drive from Ubuntu?

Comment: Yes, I have been.

Comment: Then that's the expected result and hopefully lesson learned. Reinstall both OSes and while doing that reserve a data partition (NTFS) where you will be storing the files you need to access from both. Also keep in mind to disable Windows fastboot before installing the second OS, Ubuntu. And never again even mount the Windows system partition , the "C: drive" in Ubuntu, let alone write to it.

Comment: @CelticWarrior, you got it partially right. You don't need to reinstall both OS. In Windows, do a `chkdsk c:/f` and (you're correct about this part) turn off fastboot, and hibernation `powercfg -h off` (if memory serves me). In Ubuntu, drop into root from the GRUB menu and do a `sudo fsck -f /`. And then you CAN access the C: drive from Ubuntu without corrupting it. Cheers, Al